# Foreign Key Query to Filter Out Invalid Values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called `INSTALL` which foreign keys to another table `COMPONENT`. It is a one - many relationship respectively.

The `COMPONENT` table has values - `PW`, `APS` and `NPW`.

An `INSTALL` can have a foreign key to all 3. I want the `INSTALL` records that only have a foreign key to `NPW` or `APS` and if the `INSTALL` also references `PW` I do not want to output this in my query.

I have tried an `IN ('NPW, 'APS')` clause but this does not filter for `PW` `INSTALL`.

How can I get it to not output `PW` installs?

I have this at the moment:

```
SELECT * FROM INSTALL 
LEFT JOIN COMPONENT ON INSTALLNO = COM$INSTALL
WHERE COM$COMPONENT IN (
      'NPW',
      'APS')
```

Comment: can you provide the data model and some output example with your query ??

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM INSTALL 
INNER JOIN COMPONENT ON INSTALLNO = COM$INSTALL
WHERE COM$COMPONENT IN (
      'NPW',
      'APS')
AND COM$COMPONENT != 'PW'
```

This returns the rows with values of `COM$COMPONENT` equal to `NPW` or `APS` but different from `PW`

Now to get the data from the `COMPONENT` table that is not being referenced:

```
SELECT * FROM COMPONENT 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
       (SELECT NULL 
          FROM INSTALL 
         WHERE INSTALLNO = COM$INSTALL
           AND COM$COMPONENT IN ('NPW','APS') 
           AND COM$COMPONENT != 'PW')
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried this and it does what you say. What I want though is that the INSTALL record not be returned if it has a foreign key to `PW`.

Comment: How about with an inner join?

Comment: I've tried that too, is there a way to maybe group the components into a list for the install, then search that list for `PW` where if it exists I dont output the INSTALL?

Comment: Maybe you're looking at exists / not exists? Do you require only the columns from the `INSTALL` table of also from the `COMPONENT` table?

Comment: I need to output the components too, so need that table for outputs and the `WHERE` clause. The issue is currently I'm treating the records at the COMPONENT level, so the query will not output COMPONENT if it isnt in that list, but will output the INSTALL if it has even one of the acceptable values.

Comment: So you can't use exists/not exists because then you'd only return the values from the `INSTALL` table. And you also don't want to use the inner join because then you wouldn't get the columns of the `COMPONENT` table, right? If that's the case then I'd treat both cases differently. One with the inner join and a second with only the components. I'll add an edit on how to get those missing components.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried a couple methods of doing it. Essentially what I want is an 'Exclusive In' kind of clause (which I dont think exists in ORACLE)

Comment: Have you tried the right outer join instead of the left outer join?

Comment: I haven't, largely just been using left join

Comment: `INSTALL RIGHT JOIN COMPONENT` equals to `COMPONENT LEFT JOIN INSTALL`  This would return all of the rows from `component` and only those from `install` that match.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT * FROM INSTALL A 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM COMPONENT WHERE COM$COMPONENT != 'PW') B
ON A.INSTALLNO = B.COM$INSTALL
```